# Layout still needs update after calling NSTableRowView layout

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, autolayout, nstableview

I have two NSTableView's in my app and the user can drag and drop items from table A to table B. When dragging an item to table B Xcode gives me the following layout warning message:

> Layout still needs update after calling -[NSTableRowView layout]. 
>   NSTableRowView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout
>   without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the
>   middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa
>   Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa
>   Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.

This ever only happens when items are dragged to table B. I have otherwise no auto-layout warnings in IB and everything in the layout looks like being set up correctly. Does somebody know what the above message is trying to tell me? The tables are using standard Cocoa classes (not sub-classed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it (or rather worked around it) by having the drop operation type not being allowed except for  `NSTableViewDropOperation.Above`. Before a user could drop them *onto* other rows, not just between rows. But I want them to be only be allowed to be dropped between rows so that's fine with me. Here's the code that fixed it:

```
func tableView(aTableView:NSTableView, validateDrop info:NSDraggingInfo, proposedRow row:Int, proposedDropOperation operation:NSTableViewDropOperation) -> NSDragOperation
{
    if (operation == .Above) { return .Move; }
    return .None;
}
```

Comment: Have you found a fix for when you want to drop on the row instead of between them?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the warning was slightly different.

> Layout still needs update after calling -[NSView layout].  NSView or
>   one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout without calling
>   super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the middle of updating
>   it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is
>   pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method
>   called layout, but it should be fixed.

Different class `NSView`.

Anyway in my case, I could fix this by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == false` of a `NSScrollView`.

For the record, `autoresizingMask` and `autoresizesSubviews` don't need to be touched at all.

The warning simply means that I have to set the property manually, otherwise it will produce wrong constraints. But figuring out the problematic object was very hard. I had to iterate all view nodes to check the property state.